# how to enlarge image in PHP

Tags: php

I have a class that handles both of upload and resize, what is missing in this class is it can't enlarge images dimension if the image is small, is there to modifier the method responsible for resizing images making it allow to enlarge image dimentions?

Comment: How are you currently resizing the images?

Answer (score 3):

imagecopyresample and Imagick::resizeImage both allow you to resize an image - larger or smaller.

Comment: For sure, it depends of compilation options, but either Imagick or GD (for imagecopyresample) should be available

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it would be better to scale the image with CSS rather than physically enlarging and adding file weight with no additional information.